# Convert dates from Excel to Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, date, datetime

I have a series of dates and some corresponding values. The format of the data in Excel is "Custom" `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`.
When I try to convert this column into an array in Matlab, in order to use it as the x axis of a plot, I use:

```
a = datestr(xlsread('filename.xlsx',1,'A:A'), 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM');
```

But I get a Empty string: 0-by-16.

Therefore I am not able to convert it into a date array using the function `datenum`.

Where do I make a mistake? Edit: passing from hh:mm to HH:MM doesn't work neither. when I try only

```
 a = xlsread('filename.xlsx',1,'A2')
```

I get: a = []

Comment: Can you spilt the commands into 2 (first `xlsread` then `datestr`)? That will help you narrow the problem. It may be that `xlsread` is not working for whatever reason and returning an empty result.

Comment: hh (hours) and mm (minutes) doesn't exist in matlab: use `HH` and `MM` instead. `datestr(string,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM');`

Comment: `xlsread` outputs numbers as it's first argument, so you are getting Excel serial numbers which are not the same as Matlab serial date numbers. Try either using [`x2mdate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/x2mdate.html?searchHighlight=x2mdate) if you have the finance toolbox or just adding `693960` i.e. `dates_as_numbers = xlsread('filename.xlsx',1,'A:A') + 693960`

Comment: Also is that `'A2'` a typo on your second last line? Sure it should be `'A:A'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation of `datestr`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) the syntax for minutes, months and hours is as follows:

```
HH -> Hour in two digits
MM -> Minute in two digits
mm -> Month in two digits
```

Therefore you have to change the syntax in the call for `datestr`. Because the serial date number format between Excel and Matlab differ, you have to add an offset of `693960` to the retrieved numbers from `xlsread`.

```
dateval    = xlsread('test.xls',1,'A:A') + 693960;
datestring = datestr(dateval, 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM');
```

This will read the first column (`A`) of the first sheet (`1`) in the Excel-file. For better performance you can specify the range explicitly (for example `'A1:A20'`).

*The code converts...*

[image]

*... to:*

```
datestring =
22/06/2015 16:00
```

**Edit:** The following code should work for your provided Excel-file:

```
% read from file
tbl = readtable('data.xls','ReadVariableNames',false);
dateval = tbl.(1);
dateval = dateval + 693960;
datestring = datestr(dateval)

% plot with dateticks as x-axis
plot(dateval,tbl.(2))
datetick('x','mmm/yy')
%datetick('x','dd/mmm/yy')  % this is maybe better than only the months
```

Comment: @Giovanni Rinaldi: Now my solution is tested and works as desired (Office for Mac 2011, xls-Format, Matlab 2015a).

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for your help. Unfortunately also using your code I get an empty array both for dateval and datestring. Perhaps the problem is in my Excel format date. (Office for Windows, Matlab 2013b)

Comment: Then what does just `xlsread('test.xls',1,'A:A')` return? Pay attention to the correct filename and extension(.xls or .xlsx).

Comment: I checked carefully filename and extension. I get in every case just an empty array:

    ans = 
    [ ]

Only using the function readtable I am able to visualize the dates correctly. But then I am not able to convert them into strings to use as x tick label. I am managing dates referred to different years, so at the end I would like to represent in the x axis dates in the format mmm/yy (e.g. Jan/95)

Comment: Ok definitely it is not the Excel file. Also using the one that you sent me I get only empty arrays.

Comment: can you share your excel file then?

Comment: It almost works. I get an error in the dates, because since dateval is a cell array Matlab does not allow me to add 693960 to each date (Undefined function 'plus' for input arguments of type 'cell'). I tried to convert dateval into a normal array using cell2mat, but it gives me the error "Error using cat. Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent".

There is no need to add header columns if you use tbl = readtable ('data.xls', 'ReadVariableNames', false);

Comment: In my code example, `dateval` is already a matrix. With the call of `tbl.(1)` I only get the data as matrix without headers. Use my code and it works ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Minutes need to be called with a capital M to distinguish them from months.
Use a=datestr(xlsread('filename.xlsx',1,'A:A'),'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM')

Edit: Corrected my original answer, where I had mixed up the cases needed.

Comment: that's the exact opposit: Month = mm, Minutes = MM.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this. It works but it is slow and I am not able to plot the dates at the end. Anyway:

```
table= readtable ('filename.xlsx');
dates = table(:,1);
dates = table2array (dates);
dates = datenum(dates);
dates = datestr (dates);
```

Comment: Should I add an example with tables to my answer? The table needs to have a header in the first column that will be used in the table-object as column name. Then you need to add the offset value 693960 to the array (after `table2array`). How do you want to plot the dates?